# Camel http4 download file using Basic authentication over Https

Tags: https, apache-camel, basic-authentication

I am trying to download a file from a **Https** url which requires Basic authentication. I am using HTTP4 
I am trying to download from url - https://ebc.cybersource.com/ebc/DownloadReport/xxx.csv?authMethod=Basic&authUsername=scott&authPassword=tiger

After the file is downloaded I need to save it to a folder. Here's what my code looks like

```
from(xxx)
.to("http4://ebc.cybersource.com/ebc/DownloadReport/xxx.csv?authMethod=Basic&authUsername=scott&authPassword=tiger")
.to("file:target/messages/download");
```

Here's the error I get -

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot consume from http endpoint
at org.apache.camel.component.http4.HttpEndpoint.createConsumer(HttpEndpoint.java:120)
at org.apache.camel.impl.EventDrivenConsumerRoute.addServices(EventDrivenConsumerRoute.java:65)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRoute.onStartingServices(DefaultRoute.java:85)
at org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService.warmUp(RouteService.java:158)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWarmUpRoutes(DefaultCamelContext.java:3090)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.safelyStartRouteServices(DefaultCamelContext.java:3020)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartOrResumeRoutes(DefaultCamelContext.java:2797)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:2653)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.access$000(DefaultCamelContext.java:167)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:2467)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:2463)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWithDefinedClassLoader(DefaultCamelContext.java:2486)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:2463)
at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:2432)
at com.dinesh.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:29)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

Now the documentation says I need to use HttpContext,

```
    public class HttpContextFactory {

  private String httpHost = "localhost";
  private String httpPort = 9001;

  private BasicHttpContext httpContext = new BasicHttpContext();
  private BasicAuthCache authCache = new BasicAuthCache();
  private BasicScheme basicAuth = new BasicScheme();

  public HttpContext getObject() {
    authCache.put(new HttpHost(httpHost, httpPort), basicAuth);

    httpContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.AUTH_CACHE, authCache);

    return httpContext;
  }

  // getter and setter
}
```

I tried that but I am still getting errors.

**UPDATE**
I am actually using a quartz scheduler to trigger

```
 from("quartz2://foo?cron=0/2+*+*+?+*+MON-FRI").multicast().stopOnException().to("direct:downLoadFile");

        from("direct:downLoadFile")
                .to("http4://ebc.cybersource.com/ebc/DownloadReport/2015/04/16/us_voip/us_voip.au.response.ss.csv?authMethod=Basic&authUserName=xxxx&authPassword=yyyy")
                .log("File Downloaded");
```

When I run this I get the below error.

```
[                          main] QuartzComponent                INFO  Starting scheduler.
[                          main] QuartzScheduler                INFO  Scheduler DefaultQuartzScheduler-camel-1_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
[                          main] DefaultCamelContext            INFO  Total 2 routes, of which 2 is started.
[                          main] DefaultCamelContext            INFO  Apache Camel 2.15.1 (CamelContext: camel-1) started in 0.938 seconds
[artzScheduler-camel-1_Worker-1] RetryExec                      INFO  I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {}->http://ebc.cybersource.com:80: Connection reset
[artzScheduler-camel-1_Worker-1] RetryExec                      INFO  Retrying request to {}->http://ebc.cybersource.com:80
[artzScheduler-camel-1_Worker-1] RetryExec                      INFO  I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {}->http://ebc.cybersource.com:80: Connection reset
[artzScheduler-camel-1_Worker-1] RetryExec                      INFO  Retrying request to {}->http://ebc.cybersource.com:80
[artzScheduler-camel-1_Worker-1] RetryExec                      INFO  I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {}->http://ebc.cybersource.com:80: Connection reset
[artzScheduler-camel-1_Worker-1] RetryExec                      INFO  Retrying request to {}->http://ebc.cybersource.com:80
[artzScheduler-camel-1_Worker-1] DefaultErrorHandler            ERROR Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-CN-AHONNAVA-LP-49362-1430485742705-0-1 on ExchangeId: ID-CN-AHONNAVA-LP-49362-1430485742705-0-3). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Message History
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RouteId              ProcessorId          Processor                                                                        Elapsed (ms)
[route1            ] [route1            ] [quartz2://foo?cron=0%2F2+*+*+%3F+*+MON-FRI                                    ] [       523]
[route1            ] [multicast1        ] [multicast                                                                     ] [       520]
[route1            ] [to1               ] [direct:downLoadFile                                                           ] [       513]
[route2            ] [to2               ] [http4://ebc.cybersource.com/ebc:443/DownloadReport/2015/04/16/us_voip/us_voip.] [       510]

Exchange
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exchange[
    Id                  ID-CN-AHONNAVA-LP-49362-1430485742705-0-3
    ExchangePattern     InOnly
    Headers             {breadcrumbId=ID-CN-AHONNAVA-LP-49362-1430485742705-0-1, calendar=null, CamelRedelivered=false, CamelRedeliveryCounter=0, fireTime=Fri May 01 09:09:04 EDT 2015, jobDetail=JobDetail 'Camel_camel-1.foo':  jobClass: 'org.apache.camel.component.quartz2.CamelJob concurrentExectionDisallowed: false persistJobDataAfterExecution: false isDurable: false requestsRecovers: false, jobInstance=org.apache.camel.component.quartz2.CamelJob@6e61a2e3, jobRunTime=-1, mergedJobDataMap=org.quartz.JobDataMap@2a207ff6, nextFireTime=Fri May 01 09:09:06 EDT 2015, previousFireTime=null, refireCount=0, result=null, scheduledFireTime=Fri May 01 09:09:04 EDT 2015, scheduler=org.quartz.impl.StdScheduler@1e79d438, trigger=Trigger 'Camel_camel-1.foo':  triggerClass: 'org.quartz.impl.triggers.CronTriggerImpl calendar: 'null' misfireInstruction: 1 nextFireTime: Fri May 01 09:09:06 EDT 2015, triggerGroup=Camel_camel-1, triggerName=foo}
    BodyType            null
    Body                [Body is null]
]

Stacktrace
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:196)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:136)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:152)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:270)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:140)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:260)
    at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:161)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:153)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:271)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:123)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:254)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:195)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:86)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
    at org.apache.camel.component.http4.HttpProducer.executeMethod(HttpProducer.java:258)
    at org.apache.camel.component.http4.HttpProducer.process(HttpProducer.java:158)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:129)
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:448)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:118)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
    at org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:51)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:129)
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:448)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.doProcessSequential(MulticastProcessor.java:590)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.doProcessSequential(MulticastProcessor.java:518)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.process(MulticastProcessor.java:227)
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.loadbalancer.QueueLoadBalancer.process(QueueLoadBalancer.java:44)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:109)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerSupport.process(LoadBalancerSupport.java:87)
    at org.apache.camel.component.quartz2.CamelJob.execute(CamelJob.java:56)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
[artzScheduler-camel-1_Worker-1] CamelJob                       ERROR Error processing exchange. Exchange[Message: [Body is null]]. Caused by: [org.quartz.JobExecutionException - org.apache.camel.CamelExchangeException: Sequential processing failed for number 0. Exchange[Message: [Body is null]]. Caused by: [java.net.SocketException - Connection reset]]
[artzScheduler-camel-1_Worker-1] JobRunShell                    INFO  Job Camel_camel-1.foo threw a JobExecutionException: 
org.quartz.JobExecutionException: org.apache.camel.CamelExchangeException: Sequential processing failed for number 0. Exchange[Message: [Body is null]]. Caused by: [java.net.SocketException - Connection reset] [See nested exception: org.apache.camel.CamelExchangeException: Sequential processing failed for number 0. Exchange[Message: [Body is null]]. Caused by: [java.net.SocketException - Connection reset]]
    at org.apache.camel.component.quartz2.CamelJob.execute(CamelJob.java:59)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
```

**FINAL UPDATE: SOLVED**
 Thanks to @Claus Ibsen who provided the correct component. All I had to was use use https4 instead of http. Note this information is missing in camel documentation. Here's the final code, that download the file from the website and saves in in target/download folder.

```
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

/**
 * Created by darora on 4/30/2015.
 */
public class SchedulerRoute extends RouteBuilder {
    //TODO Move this to properties file
    String userCredentials ="userName:Password";
    String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(new Base64().encode(userCredentials.getBytes()));
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        //from("timer://foo?fixedRate=true&period=6000").to("bean:logBean?method=sayHello");
        //from("scheduler://foo?delay=500").to("bean:logBean?method=sayHello");
        from("quartz2://foo?cron=0/2+*+*+?+*+MON-FRI").multicast().stopOnException().to("direct:downLoadFile","direct:myBean");


        from("direct:myBean").log("Scheduler Started one more time .....")
                .to("bean:downLoadFileBean?method=updatedatabase");
        from("direct:downLoadFile").log("Scheduler Started one more time .....")
            .setHeader("Authorization",constant(basicAuth))
        .to("https4://ebc.cybersource.com/ebc/DownloadReport/2015/04/16/us_voip/us_voip.au.response.ss.csv")
                .to("file:target/download")
                .log("file is downloaded ..........");



    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot start from http4 as the exception tells you, you need a timer or something to trigger the route

```
from("timer:foo?period=5000")
.to("http4://ebc.cybersource.com/ebc/DownloadReport/xxx.csv?authMethod=Basic&authUsername=scott&authPassword=tiger")
.to("file:target/messages/download");
```

In this example the timer triggers every 5th second.

Comment: My code actually start from a timer, I just pasted a sample code. I have tried both from and to component, I think posted an incomplete code where I was doing a trial and error . The issue is that this is "https" url and when I use http4 component, it tries to post to http: // "ebc.xxx"; url instead of https://"ebc.xxx"; Please see my EDIT above.

Comment: Ah if you want to use HTTPS then use https4 as the component name, that is the one for secure.

Comment: Awesone!! that worked. Thanks a lot @Claus. I don't think "https4" documentation is available on the camel website. I also wanted to do base64 encoding, but figured out where to add this in the header. I will update my post above and provide the final solution. As a user can I update the documentation or add an example of showing how to do this?

Comment: Is there any way to preserve the filename at target/messages/download to the original filename that was downloaded?                                                           I tried something like .to("file:target/messages/download?fileName=${file:onlyname}") but that yields null and Camel seems to revert to the internal message ID as a file name

Comment: Look at the headers returned from the http call, it may have the file name