# Cannot consume from http endpoint

Tags: http, apache-camel

My route is given below i am trying to exchange data using HTTP component , the URI contains submit data and get in response should get an data but its not working

```
  <route>
    <from uri="http://gatest.dnb.com/daasaccess/scripts/broker.asp?request=%3C%3Fxml+version%3D%271.0%27+encoding%3D%27UTF-8%27%3F%3E%3CDGX%3E%3CSIGNONMSGSRQV1%3E%3CSONRQ%3E%3CDTCLIENT%3E2007-05-04%3C%2FDTCLIENT%3E%3CUSERID%3Esalesautomation%3C%2FUSERID%3E%3CUSERPASS%3ESFAAdmin%3C%2FUSERPASS%3E%3CLANGUAGE%3EEN%3C%2FLANGUAGE%3E%3CFI%3E%3CORG%3EDandB%3C%2FORG%3E%3C%2FFI%3E%3CAPPID%3EXML%3C%2FAPPID%3E%3CAPPVER%3E0010%3C%2FAPPVER%3E%3C%2FSONRQ%3E%3C%2FSIGNONMSGSRQV1%3E%3CCREDITMSGSRQV2%3E%3CDATATRNRQ%3E%3CTRNUID%3E2D995FE0173B2C%3C%2FTRNUID%3E%3CDATARQ%3E%3CSRVRTID%3E%3C%2FSRVRTID%3E%3CSVC_TYPE_CD%3E%3C%2FSVC_TYPE_CD%3E%3CREAS_CD%3E%3C%2FREAS_CD%3E%3CCUST_ENDR%3E%3C%2FCUST_ENDR%3E%3CCUST_RQ%3E%3C%2FCUST_RQ%3E%3CREFRESH_IND%3E%3C%2FREFRESH_IND%3E%3CIGNORE_REQD_FLDS_IND%3E%3C%2FIGNORE_REQD_FLDS_IND%3E%3CSUBJ_DET%3E%3CDUNS_NBR%3E829654420%3C%2FDUNS_NBR%3E%3CCTRY_CD%3E%3C%2FCTRY_CD%3E%3CTRD_UP_IND%3E%3C%2FTRD_UP_IND%3E%3CPRIM_NME%3E%3C%2FPRIM_NME%3E%3CBUS_REGN_NBR%3E%3C%2FBUS_REGN_NBR%3E%3CBUS_REGN_NBR_TYPE_CD%3E%3C%2FBUS_REGN_NBR_TYPE_CD%3E%3CADR_LINE%3E%3C%2FADR_LINE%3E%3CPOST_TOWN%3E%3C%2FPOST_TOWN%3E%3CPRIM_GEO_AREA%3E%3C%2FPRIM_GEO_AREA%3E%3CPOST_CODE%3E%3C%2FPOST_CODE%3E%3CTLCM_NBR%3E%3C%2FTLCM_NBR%3E%3C%2FSUBJ_DET%3E%3CPROD%3EEnterprise+Management%3C%2FPROD%3E%3CPROD_TYPE_CD%3ED%3C%2FPROD_TYPE_CD%3E%3CDELV_REQS_NOW%3E%3CDELV_MODE_CD%3EDIRECT%3C%2FDELV_MODE_CD%3E%3CDELV_FMT_CD%3EXML%3C%2FDELV_FMT_CD%3E%3CLANG%3EEN%3C%2FLANG%3E%3CDELV_EMAIL%3E%3C%2FDELV_EMAIL%3E%3CDELV_EMAIL_CC%3E%3C%2FDELV_EMAIL_CC%3E%3C%2FDELV_REQS_NOW%3E%3CDELV_REQS_INV%3E%3CDELV_MODE_CD%3E%3C%2FDELV_MODE_CD%3E%3CDELV_FMT_CD%3E%3C%2FDELV_FMT_CD%3E%3CLANG%3E%3C%2FLANG%3E%3CDELV_EMAIL%3E%3C%2FDELV_EMAIL%3E%3CDELV_EMAIL_CC%3E%3C%2FDELV_EMAIL_CC%3E%3C%2FDELV_REQS_INV%3E%3CDELV_REQS_NTFY%3E%3CDELV_MODE_CD%3E%3C%2FDELV_MODE_CD%3E%3CDELV_FMT_CD%3E%3C%2FDELV_FMT_CD%3E%3CLANG%3E%3C%2FLANG%3E%3CDELV_EMAIL%3E%3C%2FDELV_EMAIL%3E%3CDELV_EMAIL_CC%3E%3C%2FDELV_EMAIL_CC%3E%3C%2FDELV_REQS_NTFY%3E%3C%2FDATARQ%3E%3C%2FDATATRNRQ%3E%3C%2FCREDITMSGSRQV2%3E%3C%2FDGX%3E"/>
    <log message="starting....."/>
    <process ref="nextgenProcessor"/>
    <to uri="file://src/test"/>
    <log message="ending....."/>
  </route>
```

I am getting below error :

```
[ERROR] Error occurred while running main from: org.apache.camel.spring.Main
[ERROR] 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.camel.maven.RunMojo$1.run(RunMojo.java:488)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot consume from http endpoint
```

Comment: What happens when you call the same url with curl or wget ?

Comment: Similar to the issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29981142/camel-http4-download-file-using-basic-authentication-over-https

Comment: @AshokNanda I have used http4 as well but it isnt working..

Comment: @Marged i dont know how to use curl or wget in camel...can you help me with this?

Comment: I didn't mean you should use it from a camel route, use it from the shell to verify your approach

Answer (score 5):

Basically the error message is correct, you cannot use the [http component](http://camel.apache.org/http.html) as a consumer.  However the documentation is kind of unhelpful.  The first line says "*The http: component provides HTTP based endpoints for **consuming** external HTTP resources*" but then in the next section it states "*You can only **produce** to endpoints generated by the HTTP component. Therefore it should never be used as input into your camel Routes.*"

One approach would be to use something like the 'direct' or 'quartz2' components as the consumer, then use the 'http' component in a producer.  For example, this route will run every minute, submit to the URL specified and save the response in /tmp with a timestamped filename :-

```
<route id="httpFetch">
    <from uri="quartz2://httpFetch?cron=00+/1+*+?+*+1-5" />
    <to uri="http://gatest.dnb.com/daasaccess/scripts/broker.asp?request=%3C%3Fxml+version%3D%271.0%27+encoding%3D%27UTF-8%27%3F%3E%3CDGX%3E%3CSIGNONMSGSRQV1%3E%3CSONRQ%3E%3CDTCLIENT%3E2007-05-04%3C%2FDTCLIENT%3E%3CUSERID%3Esalesautomation%3C%2FUSERID%3E%3CUSERPASS%3ESFAAdmin%3C%2FUSERPASS%3E%3CLANGUAGE%3EEN%3C%2FLANGUAGE%3E%3CFI%3E%3CORG%3EDandB%3C%2FORG%3E%3C%2FFI%3E%3CAPPID%3EXML%3C%2FAPPID%3E%3CAPPVER%3E0010%3C%2FAPPVER%3E%3C%2FSONRQ%3E%3C%2FSIGNONMSGSRQV1%3E%3CCREDITMSGSRQV2%3E%3CDATATRNRQ%3E%3CTRNUID%3E2D995FE0173B2C%3C%2FTRNUID%3E%3CDATARQ%3E%3CSRVRTID%3E%3C%2FSRVRTID%3E%3CSVC_TYPE_CD%3E%3C%2FSVC_TYPE_CD%3E%3CREAS_CD%3E%3C%2FREAS_CD%3E%3CCUST_ENDR%3E%3C%2FCUST_ENDR%3E%3CCUST_RQ%3E%3C%2FCUST_RQ%3E%3CREFRESH_IND%3E%3C%2FREFRESH_IND%3E%3CIGNORE_REQD_FLDS_IND%3E%3C%2FIGNORE_REQD_FLDS_IND%3E%3CSUBJ_DET%3E%3CDUNS_NBR%3E829654420%3C%2FDUNS_NBR%3E%3CCTRY_CD%3E%3C%2FCTRY_CD%3E%3CTRD_UP_IND%3E%3C%2FTRD_UP_IND%3E%3CPRIM_NME%3E%3C%2FPRIM_NME%3E%3CBUS_REGN_NBR%3E%3C%2FBUS_REGN_NBR%3E%3CBUS_REGN_NBR_TYPE_CD%3E%3C%2FBUS_REGN_NBR_TYPE_CD%3E%3CADR_LINE%3E%3C%2FADR_LINE%3E%3CPOST_TOWN%3E%3C%2FPOST_TOWN%3E%3CPRIM_GEO_AREA%3E%3C%2FPRIM_GEO_AREA%3E%3CPOST_CODE%3E%3C%2FPOST_CODE%3E%3CTLCM_NBR%3E%3C%2FTLCM_NBR%3E%3C%2FSUBJ_DET%3E%3CPROD%3EEnterprise+Management%3C%2FPROD%3E%3CPROD_TYPE_CD%3ED%3C%2FPROD_TYPE_CD%3E%3CDELV_REQS_NOW%3E%3CDELV_MODE_CD%3EDIRECT%3C%2FDELV_MODE_CD%3E%3CDELV_FMT_CD%3EXML%3C%2FDELV_FMT_CD%3E%3CLANG%3EEN%3C%2FLANG%3E%3CDELV_EMAIL%3E%3C%2FDELV_EMAIL%3E%3CDELV_EMAIL_CC%3E%3C%2FDELV_EMAIL_CC%3E%3C%2FDELV_REQS_NOW%3E%3CDELV_REQS_INV%3E%3CDELV_MODE_CD%3E%3C%2FDELV_MODE_CD%3E%3CDELV_FMT_CD%3E%3C%2FDELV_FMT_CD%3E%3CLANG%3E%3C%2FLANG%3E%3CDELV_EMAIL%3E%3C%2FDELV_EMAIL%3E%3CDELV_EMAIL_CC%3E%3C%2FDELV_EMAIL_CC%3E%3C%2FDELV_REQS_INV%3E%3CDELV_REQS_NTFY%3E%3CDELV_MODE_CD%3E%3C%2FDELV_MODE_CD%3E%3CDELV_FMT_CD%3E%3C%2FDELV_FMT_CD%3E%3CLANG%3E%3C%2FLANG%3E%3CDELV_EMAIL%3E%3C%2FDELV_EMAIL%3E%3CDELV_EMAIL_CC%3E%3C%2FDELV_EMAIL_CC%3E%3C%2FDELV_REQS_NTFY%3E%3C%2FDATARQ%3E%3C%2FDATATRNRQ%3E%3C%2FCREDITMSGSRQV2%3E%3C%2FDGX%3E"/>
    <to uri="file:/tmp?fileName=data-${date:now:yyyyMMdd-HHmm}.xml&amp;tempFileName=data-${date:now:yyyyMMdd-HHmm}.xml.part" />
</route>
```

Answer (score 2):

You must specify the component, which would be responsible of consumption from http:

```
from("jetty:http://localhost:8080/test")
    .to(...something else...);
```

Don't forget to include the component's jar into your maven/gradle project.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do this way:

```
<route>
<from uri="timer://runOnce?repeatCount=1&delay=1000"/>
<to uri="http://your-url"/>
<log message="starting....."/>
<process ref="nextgenProcessor"/>
<to uri="file://src/test"/>
<log message="ending....."/>
```