# Simplifying Multicasting and aggregating REST endpoints in camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

Trying to implement scatter-gather pattern in camel, so I'm sending a message to 3 different webservices and want to aggregate their response. I get it to work, but it looks really convoluted. Trying to clean up the mess it throws and exception.

This works:

```
@Component
public class ProductBestPriceRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        from("timer://foo?repeatCount=10")
                .multicast()
                .to("direct:a")
                .to("direct:b")
                .to("direct:c");

        from("direct:a")
                .to("http4:localhost:9090/simple/product/foo")
                .to("direct:aggregate");

        from("direct:b")
                .to("http4:localhost:9091/simple/product/foo")
                .to("direct:aggregate");

        from("direct:c")
                .to("http4:localhost:9092/simple/product/foo")
                .to("direct:aggregate");

        from("direct:aggregate").log("${body}");
    }
```

This doesn't and throws an exception:

> UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot consume from http endpoint

```
  @Component
    public class ProductBestPriceRoute extends RouteBuilder {

        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            from("timer://foo?repeatCount=10")
                    .multicast()
                    .to("http4:localhost:9090/simple/product/foo")
                    .to("http4:localhost:9091/simple/product/foo")
                    .to("http4:localhost:9092/simple/product/foo");

            from("http4:localhost:9090/simple/product/foo").to("direct:aggregate");
            from("http4:localhost:9091/simple/product/foo").to("direct:aggregate");
            from("http4:localhost:9092/simple/product/foo").to("direct:aggregate");

            from("direct:aggregate").log("${body}");
        }
    }
```

Camel 2.20.1

Camel-http4 2.20.1

Spring boot 1.5.9.RELEASE

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-zookeeper</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-gson</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-http4</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot consume from http endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34035908/cannot-consume-from-http-endpoint)

Comment: You can use `AggregationStrategy` directly with the multicast to aggregate the responses, then you dont need all that extra stuff.