# Apache camel http4 authentication

Tags: apache, routes, apache-camel

I am trying to route to intranet website to crawl the content.Below is my code

```
 from(DIRECT_INITIAL_CRAWL).setHeader(HTTP_METHOD, constant(GET))
 .to(http4://test.com:443/?
authMethod=BASIC&authUsername=name&authPassword=pwd&authHost=test.com)
```

but i am, getting

> org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException:
>   test.com:443 failed to respond. at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:141)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:163)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:165)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:272)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.component.http4.HttpProducer.executeMethod(HttpProducer.java:334)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.component.http4.HttpProducer.process(HttpProducer.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:148)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
>     at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:138)   at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:101)    at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:62)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:148)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.ChoiceProcessor.process(ChoiceProcessor.java:117)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.TryProcessor.process(TryProcessor.java:113)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.TryProcessor.process(TryProcessor.java:84)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:62)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:148)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
>     at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:138)   at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:101)    at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.TryProcessor.process(TryProcessor.java:113)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.TryProcessor.process(TryProcessor.java:84)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:62)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.SharedCamelInternalProcessor.process(SharedCamelInternalProcessor.java:186)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.SharedCamelInternalProcessor.process(SharedCamelInternalProcessor.java:86)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache$1.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:541)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache$1.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:506)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:369)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.sendExchange(ProducerCache.java:506)
>     at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.send(ProducerCache.java:229)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.send(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:144)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.sendBody(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:161)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.sendBody(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:168)
>     at
>   com.abnamro.ees.connections.crawler.main.ApplicationMain.main(ApplicationMain.java:82)

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: have you tried reached that endpoint from browser? does that work?

Comment: Yes...I have tried in the browser and it worked

Comment: Did u check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40295168/apache-camel-https4-basic-authentication

Comment: Yes I have tried that and the actual content to crawl is behind proxy and I tried with proxy parameters as well still same error

Comment: And also I have the saml sso authentication is enabled.I guess the error is because of that

Comment: `443` port is generally used for `https`. Try using `https4`